# Disconnect-ExchangeOnline in a script

Tags: powershell, office365

I developed a PowerShell script that uses EXO V2 module. At the beggining, I connect to Exchange Online via:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $Credential
```

after my stuff is done, I'd like to disconnect from Exchange Online, but

```
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline
```

asks for confirmation. Also adding -Confirm switch seems not changing the behavior.
I'd like to schedule the script, so confirmation is a problem. Is there any way to disconnect without confirmation ? Or can I simple not disconnect ? I found this possibility somewhere, but I've concerns regarding security issues when leaving an open connection.

Comment: Did you try the `-Confirm:$false` switch?

Comment: yes, you're right, the default is $true... shame on me....